# Unable to Link Custom Play Store Listing with Branch.io

Tags: android, google-play, branch.io

Google Play Store has recently introduced the capability to create custom store listings to cater to different audience segments using unique URLs. However, when attempting to use a custom URL in conjunction with branch.io, I encountered an issue where it redirected me to the default Play Store listing instead of the intended custom listing.

Answer (score 0):

Some custom playstore listing URL do not support branch links.As a workaround we can use a bit.ly link to wrap the Play Store link that has a listing tag and an issue with Branch link redirection.Configure bit.ly link as redirect target for Android, this should solve the issue.